# ZAP: Evaluate / Show response in browser

Tags: web-application, tools, zap

Let's say I've edited a request and successfully found a XSS vulnerability. Now, I want to validate that in the browser.

However, since the payload was sent with `POST`, I can't just use "Open URL in browser" since it would not send that `POST` data and exploit the XSS.

I could write an HTML form that does that for me, but is there a way to do that directly from ZAP?

Comment: Please comment after you downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is with the ZAP HUD, which is not yet in the main release but is in the weekly releases: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud

The HUD runs in the browser so when you display a request you'll see an option to Resend in Browser :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option it to open the (GET) request in the browser, then resubmit it with break turned on. The GET request will be intercepted by ZAP and you can then change it to a POST with the relevant data.